# Can a Google App Script download a zipped csv file via a link and parse that CSV?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a link to a zipped csv sent to gmail. I have to click to download, is it possible to write a script that takes the link and extracts the csv file from it, unzips it and parses it? I am able to parse an attachment, unsure how to proceed with a link to a file. The link is not a link to a Google drive file.

Comment: I think that you can achieve it using the following flow. 1. Download the zip file from the URL using [UrlFetchApp.fetch()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String)). 2. Unzip the downloaded zip file using [Utilities.unzip()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#unzipblob). 3. Parse the unzipped csv using [Utilities.parseCsv()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#parsecsvcsv).

Answer (score 0):

Tanaike was correct: 1. Download the zip file from the URL using UrlFetchApp.fetch(). 2. Unzip the downloaded zip file using Utilities.unzip(). 3. Parse the unzipped csv using Utilities.parseCsv().